# WordPress popular posts how to show posts like category?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm using plugin (wordpress popular posts) that's allow me to create side-bar widget (www.humnutrition.com/blog/), but if you click on other category like (BEAUTY, SCIENCE etc.), WP will render new page with posts in that category. May be we have some easy way to that with (MOST POPULAR)? Basically create new category which will render page with all posts from "popular" widget?

I'm javascript developer, so I'm not so strong in php, but any way, don't want to waste a lot of time on basic tasks for WP, so maybe someone know easiest way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create a normal wordpress page and use the plugins [shortcodes](https://github.com/cabrerahector/wordpress-popular-posts/wiki/1.-Using-WPP-on-posts-&-pages) to show the posts.

`[wpp range="monthly" stats_views=1 order_by="views"]`

This would output the most viewed posts from the last 30 days.